# What is the proper way to save an existing file to a user's computer using a SaveFileDialog?

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I have a vb.net windows app that creates a PDF.  After creation, I want to prompt the user where they want to save the file.  The default save folder is different than the folder of the created PDF.  I get the SaveDialog box to come up with the default folder and file name that I want.  If I choose "Save", I get a message saying that the file does not exist and none of the code below the ShowDialog is executed (I'm sure that I'm doing that part wrong as well).

```
Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
      saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = MyDocsFolder
      saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Report.pdf"
      saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Report"
      saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
      saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
      saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "pdf"
      saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
      saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
      saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
      saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
      If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
          If saveFileDialog1.FileName() <> "" Then
              Dim newStream As FileStream = File.Open(newFile, FileMode.Open)
              Dim pdfStream As New FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create)
              newStream.CopyTo(fs, FileMode.Append)
              newStream.Close()
              fs.Close()
          End If
      End If
```

Comment: The SaveDialog part of it looks fundamentially ok to me, where I think your problem is Dim newStream As FileStream = File.Open(newFile, FileMode.Open).  Your trying to open an existing file here.  Not sure what the intent of newStream.  Think you just want Dim pdfStream as FileStream = File.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName).  Also have  fs variable in there popped in from no where.

Comment: saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = False

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class Form1
    Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
        Dim Path As String
        Using SFD1 As New CommonSaveFileDialog
            SFD1.Title = "Where should the file be saved?"
            SFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("PDF", ".pdf"))
            SFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            If SFD1.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = SFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        Dim dest As IO.FileInfo
        Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create(Path & ".pdf")
            dest = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fs.Name)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please note that I am using a FileDialog that I downloaded from Visual Studios' own Nuget Package Manager. See image. You don't have to do that, but I prefer this FileDialog because it offers more options than the one that is already included.

So the user enters the file name; thus the path results. In my code example, this creates a blank PDF. It cannot be opened like this yet.
So that something is written in the PDF, you can download itext7 (also via NuGet).

Then, you write `Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf`,
`Imports iText.Kernel.Utils` and in your sub `Dim pdfwriter As New PdfWriter(dest)` with ‘dest’ from above.
[image: NuGet, download FileDialog]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I haven't tried out the FileDialog that you are using yet, but  my problem is that when I press "Save" I immediately get a "file does not exist" message.  It doesn't create any file and I can never get past the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I am so blind and stupid...

saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.